# переход из внутреннего if-else на внешний else

Tags: python, if

Имеется два условия if-else для python, одно условие содержится внутри другого, как выполнить переход из внутреннего else на строку с внешним else - если возможно?

```
if True:

        if False:
            pass
        else:   # как отсюда сделать переход

else:
   pass # сюда
```

вот подробное описание

из строки текста нужно выбрать и вырезать числа

которые имеют фиксированную разрядность =dig

которые могут быть как внутри скобок () в конце строки - ведём поиск справа

и могут быть без скобок в начале строки - поиск слева

поиск в разных направлениях должен сократить время обработки, но пока без замеров

использовать re - не уверен что оправдано

делаем так

```
if '(' in txt:                      # если скобок нет - начать поиск слева
    ss = txt.rfind('(')
    num = txt[ss + 1: ss + dig + 1] #dig - количество разрядов
    if num.isdigit():               # если в скобках не число - начать поиск слева
        txt = txt.replace(num, '').replace('()', '')

else:
    for i, c in enumerate(txt):
        if c.isdigit():
            num = txt[i:i+dig]
            if num.isdigit():
                txt = txt.replace(num, '')
                break
```

Comment: Никак, выполнение уже пошло по первой ветке условия. Что-то не так с логикой, ее надо менять.

Comment: а ты жосткий парень :)

Answer (score 1):

У вас там всё-таки какие-то реальные условия, поэтому перепишу на них:

```py
if cond1:
    if not cond2:
        pass
    else:   # как отсюда сделать переход
else:
    pass # сюда
```

Это можно записать так, если `cond2` известно сразу и между `if`-ами ничего не происходит:

```py
if cond1 and not cond2:
    pass
else:
    pass # сюда
```

Если же что-то происходит внутри первого `if` или `cond2` как-то вычисляется внутри, то можно так:

```py
flag = not cond1
if cond1:
    if not cond2:
        pass
    else:   # как отсюда сделать переход
        flag = True
    if not flag:
        # тут ещё какой-то код, который нужно пропустить
if flag:
    pass # сюда
```

Answer (score 0):

Соглашусь с комментарием, что никак. Возможно автор хотел использовать прыжки, как в других ЯП, но этого питон не умеет.

Единственное, если очень не хочется переделывать логику, то можно сделать очень глупую функцию, в которую запихать что надо делать. И Вызывать ее из 2ух мест:

```
def stupid_func():
    print(10)
    
if True:
    if False:
        pass
    else:
        stupid_func()# как отсюда сделать переход

else:
   stupid_func() # сюда
```

Как итог, будет напечатано 10. НО! Еще раз повторюсь - это очень глупо и так не стоит делать!

**Лучше изменить логику!**

Answer (score 0):

Желательно, чтобы вы описали подробнее, так как логически можно разделить на два блока с условиями и не использовать внутренний `if`, а добавить флаг, что условие для перехода в следующий `if` было выполнено

```py
if False:
  flag = False
  pass
else:   # как отсюда сделать переход (ваше)
  flag = True

if True and flag:
  # пришли сюда
  pass
```